# What are the advantages of using more then 1 code file for a project? (C++)

Tags: c++, code-organization, projects-and-solutions

What are the advantages of using multiple source (`.cpp`) and header (`.h`) files in a single project?

Is it just a preferential thing or are there true benefits?

Comment: Some files may then by included in multiple projects. And don't you get lost in a file of 1000lines? What about scrolling to funcion predefinitions all the time?

Comment: My company's code is some 30000 cpp files, each with 1000-20000 lines.  I don't want to be dealing with a 4GB file of code.

Comment: @MooingDuck I don’t want to be dealing with a 20000 lines file, to be honest. ;-)

Comment: I'm still just learning, so the largest I've ever dealt with is about 6 or 7 hundred lines of my own code, I guess that explains why I prefer one file. The tutorials I'm reading split files with only 10 to 100 lines of code into multiple files.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It helps you split your code and sort it by theme. Otherwise you get one file with 1000s of lines… which is hard to manage…

Usually, people have .h and .c for one or sometimes a few classes.
Also, it speeds up compilation, since only the modified files, and some related files need to be recompiled.

From [Organizing Code Files in C and C++](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/general-programming/organizing-code-files-in-c-and-c-r1798):

Splitting any reasonably-sized project up buys you some advantages,
   the most significant of which are the following:

- **Speed up compilation** - most compilers work on a file at a time. So if all your
  10000 lines of code is in one file, and you change one line, then you
  have to recompile 10000 lines of code. On the other hand, if your
  10000 lines of code are spread evenly across 10 files, then changing
  one line will only require 1000 lines of code to be recompiled. The
  9000 lines in the other 9 files will not need recompiling. (Linking
  time is unaffected.)
- **Increase organization** -  Splitting your code along logical lines will
  make it easier for you (and any other programmers on the project) to
  find functions, variables, struct/class declarations, and so on. Even
  with the ability to jump directly to a given identifier that is
  provided in many editors and development environments (such as
  Microsoft Visual C++), there will always be times when you need to
  scan the code manually to look for something. Just as splitting the
  code up reduces the amount of code you need to recompile, it also
  reduces the amount of code you need to read in order to find
  something. Imagine that you need to find a fix you made to the sound
  code a few weeks ago. If you have one large file called GAME.C,
  that's potentially a lot of searching. If you have several small
  files called GRAPHICS.C, MAINLOOP.C, SOUND.C, and INPUT.C, you know
  where to look, cutting your browsing time by 3/4.
- **Facilitate code reuse** - If your code is carefully split up into
  sections that operate largely independently of each other, this lets
  you use that code in another project, saving you a lot of rewriting
  later. There is a lot more to writing reusable code than just using a
  logical file organization, but without such an organization it is
  very difficult to know which parts of the code work together and
  which do not. Therefore putting subsystems and classes in a single
  file or carefully delineated set of files will help you later if you
  try to use that code in another project.
- **Share code between projects** - The principle here is the same as with
  the reuse issue. By carefully separating code into certain files, you
  make it possible for multiple projects to use some of the same code
  files without duplicating them. The benefit of sharing a code file
  between projects rather than just using copy-and-paste is that any
  bug fixes you make to that file or files from one project will affect
  the other project, so both projects can be sure of using the most
  up-to-date version.
- **Split coding responsibilities among programmers** - For really large
  projects, this is perhaps the main reason for separating code into
  multiple files. It isn't practical for more than one person to be
  making changes to a single file at any given time. Therefore you
  would need to use multiple files so that each programmer can be
  working on a separate part of the code without affecting the file
  that the other programmers are editing. Of course, there still have
  to be checks that 2 programmers don't try altering the same file;
  configuration management systems and version control systems such as
  CVS or MS SourceSafe help you here. All of the above can be
  considered to be aspects of modularity, a key element of both
  structured and object-oriented design.

Then, they go on about *How to do it*, *Potential Pitfalls*, *Fixing problems*, etc.

You should check it.

Comment: one file with thousands of lines of code is not "hard to manage". It's just overwhelming for beginners because they've likely never seen anything like it before.

Answer (score 11):

Code files become unmaintainable (try searching in them!) after a few hundred lines. Some people go up to a few thousand (but this is already a problem). Even small projects have thousands of lines, medium projects have tens of thousands of lines, and big projects have millions of lines. Text editors cannot cope with files this big (but programmers themselves cannot either).

Splitting a project into different source files is also *necessary* if you want to separate your project into different compilation units, which makes compilation much faster because only parts of the projects need to be recompiled.

A few decades ago programs used to be written in one single file / stack of cards. However, these programs were tiny in comparison to modern programs, and completely unmaintainable – even small changes essentially necessitated a rewrite, which put a fixed upper limit on the complexity that could thus be achieved.

Modern, more complex projects essentially *require* splitting apart. The question of putting everything in one file is frankly one that I’ve never asked myself because the idea is simply inconceivable.

Comment: Why'd you remove the bit about how it can reduce compilation time? That was an important bit of information I didn't know and is why I upvoted.

Comment: @user1958850 I didn’t remove that …

Answer (score 2):

Different cpp files are compiled as separate compilation units. This allows you to isolate things (header inclusions, anonymous namespaces, pimpl) from the rest of the source code.

Sometimes two libraries can not be used together in one source file because they have name clashes. This can be solved by including each library header in a different cpp file and expose required functionality via corresponding header files.

Answer (score 1):

if its a small project such as hello world, there is no advantage, but imagine something like windows, or google chrome, or android.

a project of that size could not possibly be managed with a single file.

multiple files for your project are about manageability and re usability for the code.

Comment: +1 for reusability. One of the largest benefits of OO programming (C++/Java) is that you can use an MVC approach using classes to build objects that handle different things. Then anytime you need that object in another project or application, you just use your pre-existing class and import the file into your current project. Saves tons of time.

Comment: Splitting project code into files focused on one concept also removes the temptation to have classes look at the internals of other classes.