# Are there any advantages of _not_ using multiple files in a code-project? (C++)

Tags: c++, code-organization

As opposed to [What are the advantages of using more then 1 code file for a project? (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15580539/what-are-the-advantages-of-using-more-then-1-code-file-for-a-project-c) I'd like to know whether there are (technical or other) advantages of not using multiple code-files for a, for example, C++-project?

Is splitting up in several files just a human-thing? Wouldn't it be better for the machine to handle all of them at once in term of visibility/optimization?

Comment: thats the question he linked to ;)

Comment: It was this question which triggered my question which I had in mind since some time. And I think it is not just the opposite of the answer over there.

Comment: @pst with *machine* I meant any processing of the files (compilation, but also parsing and anything else).

Comment: I'm honestly confused as to why you thought the answers to this inverse question would be any different than the exact opposite of the answers to the other question. I thought about casting a vote to re-open because at first glance this clearly is not a duplicate. Besides, you have over 3k rep, presumably know about duplicates, and already read that other question since you linked to it. But then, I can't imagine what else could be said here that wouldn't apply there. So if you want to get this re-opened, an explanation would be great.

Comment: @CodyGray My question is actually whether there are advantages of having all the source code in one file (or one compilation object) or not. To ask my initial idea differently, I could ask whether it bears advantages to process all files in one compilation process to give the maximum visibility to the compiler to let it better do its job or not. It was the other question which made me ask it more generally. Maybe too generally. What should I do, to get a better answer?

Comment: I actually have good answers to my original question.

Answer (score 5):

Putting everything into a single file would defeat the purpose of of file-level static and anonymous namespaces (and obviate extern declarations).

It wouldn't really do much good to the compiler though. For things like optimization, they simply implement the parts that need global visibility into the linker (and most current linkers include such optimization/code generation capability).

It would (or at least could) reduce the overall time for a complete rebuild. With separate source files, you end re-compiling each header for each source file in which it's included. With only one source file, you'd compile these only once (but pre-compiled headers can and typically do reduce this to the point that it probably rarely matters, at least if you use them).

From a practical viewpoint, it would normally hurt build times, often dramatically. Most people try pretty hard to isolate things so changes in one part of a program only require re-compiling a fairly small piece of the program. For anything more than a truly minuscule program, having to re-compile everything every time you made any change would be thoroughly unmanageable -- for a decent-sized program, your build time change from a few seconds to several minutes.

Answer (score 4):

It's actually a subtly broken question.  It is only advantageous to split a file when it meets one of the criteria answered in the other question, i.e. when the file or project is "big enough" that it is more manageable to split.  If such criteria are not met, there are not advantages.  So the answer to this question is "if none of the reasons to split a file apply, don't split."  They usually do for even medium-sized projects.  To give a concrete example otherwise, "Hello World" should generally be kept to one file.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to send the program as an email attachment then you only need to attach one file.

Comment: That's a fair point.  And solidifies my judgment to close this question as not constructive.

Comment: If you send an archive, you only need to send one file too. Also, just tweet a link to the github/bitbucket/... repository!

Comment: I always forget about archives and end up attaching dozens of files. Thanks for reminding me!

Comment: lol having fun on a friday night

Answer (score 2):

The compiler can possibly do more optimization if everything is in one compilation unit, that is why sqlite3 is distributed that way.

Comment: This is true of *older* compilers, but almost all modern compilers support link-time code generation and other powerful optimizations that relegate this mostly to the realm of historical curiosity.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you look at [What are the advantages of using more then 1 code file for a project? (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15580539/what-are-the-advantages-of-using-more-then-1-code-file-for-a-project-c/15580555) you will see that there are many advantages to split your code. All those would be lost otherwise.

The only advantage to *not* split your code would be if you are working on a very small project. Then it is more convenient to keep everything in one file.

Most projects large enough have multiple files. You just feel the irresistible (the urge) need for them when developing. Who actually loves scrolling back and forward over 1000s of lines to make some edits?

Yes, it is a humane thing. We have to split stuff to be able to understand them. We need to work on smaller pieces of code.

Comment: This does not really help me. I'd like to know if there are advantages, during compilation or in general.

Comment: @PatrickB. And what if there are none? What if this leads to ackward editing & increased compilation time? What if there are none because compilers are *designed* to efficiently handle multi-file code?