# Why to split C files into multiple ones

Tags: c, file, split, header

First of all, I know how to split a C file into multiple ones.

My question is, is there any advantage other than readability? What is the main reason to split C files?

Comment: This [C++ answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15580555/4142924) lists some reasons... but you could have googled that yourself from your last question, faster than it took you to post a question here.

Comment: Being able to reuse specific parts in multiple products without having to rewrite it all the time is nice.  Imagine having to rewrite code to manage a USB Flash drive for every project that needed one.  Also, imagine trying to scroll through a 500,000 line main.c...

Comment: If you've a quite big project it increases the modularity, maintainability, legibility of your code. You may have some improvement in compiling time because you've just to re-compile files who depends each other. It also allows you to reuse your code wherever you want to without load it more than once in memory (decrease memory usage) and doing so you reduce the probability of making errors on copy-pasted codes.

Comment: Also helps to separate *form* and *function*.

Comment: enables hiding of data, enables localization of functionality, enhances readability, enhances testability, enables limitation of scope of functions, data definitions, data, allows for better definition of interfaces (via header files), etc

Answer (score 3):

If you split a large C file into *several* translation units, you practically have to declare the functions involved as (e.g. `extern`) in some common included header.

The advantage of splitting is that incremental build time could become slightly smaller. If you change only one statement in one function you just need to compile the file defining that function (and if that file is small, its compilation is fast). However, the compiler needs to parse all the headers. And you may want to define `static inline` functions in your header files (and that makes them bigger).

The disadvantage of splitting is that the developer might have harder time to find a given function (but tools like `ctags` help) and that the compiler could probably optimize less (e.g. won't inline some function calls, unless you enable link time optimization)

So it is a matter of taste and habit. Personally I like having C or C++ files of more than a thousand lines (and probably less than ten thousand lines), but YMMV. And I dislike projects having one function (of less than a hundred lines) per file (you'll need lots of them in such case). But having one large source file of a hundred thousand lines is generally unreasonable.

I also find source files keeping together related functions more readable (since it is simpler to search a function definition in one file than in many ones).

Notice that header files may expand to something quite big (and it is even more true in modern C++ : a standard header like `<vector>` or `<map>` may expand to more than ten thousand lines of code), e.g. `<stdio.h>` expands to two thousand lines (on my Debian/Linux/x86-64) so having lots of small source files can slow the full build time (since the compiler really sees the *preprocessed* form, after expansion of `#include` directives).

With [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), you *may* want to have a single header (including other ones) and [pre-compile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12438040/841108) it.

BTW, splitting a big file into several smaller ones, or merging several small files is not a big deal. So I think it is not very important.

In some cases (embedded C program on a small microcontroller, [Arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/) like), binary program size is very important, and that could be a reason to have many object files (so many C source files) since you'll only link those that are really needed.

Comment: *"and that could be a reason to have many object files (so many C source files) since you'll only link those that are really needed."* If that is the case, that toolchain is probably not very good. Decent embdedded linker should be able to pick only the used functions from object files.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to place the functions in a library used by possibly many different programs, then placing each function in a separate file has a distinct advantage.

Suppose the library contains 500 functions, and program1 references only 2 of those, while program2 references 150 of them. Then only 2 of the functions will be loaded into the first executable, and only 150 will be loaded into the second one.

If all of the functions were contained in a single file, all 500 functions would be loaded into each of the programs, making them very large and containing code that is never used.

Comment: This is practically true with static libraries, not with shared ones (e.g. `lib*.so` on Linux), which are very common.

Comment: True, but using shared libraries means that each platform where the program is to be executed must have the library installed in addition to the executable. When using static libraries (*.a), everything is loaded into the executable and the library need not be present anywhere except on the platform where the program is created.